# What is the problem with the href as it is not redirecting me to the desired pages in my code?

Tags: reactjs

Please look at the code tell me where is the problem because I'm not able to navigate to the desired pages inspite of mentioning the href
//The problem lies here it seems but where I dont know//

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { BiMenuAltRight } from "react-icons/bi";
import OutsideClickHandler from "react-outside-click-handler";
const Header = () => {
  const [menuOpened, setMenuOpened] = useState(false);
  const getMenuStyles = (menuOpened) => {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 800) {
      return { right: !menuOpened && "-100%" };
    }
  };
  return (
    <section className="h-wrapper">
      <div className="paddings innerWidth flexCenter h-container">
        <img src="./logo.png" alt="" width={150} />

        <OutsideClickHandler
          onOutsideClick={() => {
            setMenuOpened(false);
          }}
          <div className="flexCenter h-menu" style={getMenuStyles(menuOpened)}>
            <a href="#">Courses</a>
            <a href="#getstarted">Get Started</a>
            <a href="#value">Our Values</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
            <button className="button">
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </button>
          </div>
        </OutsideClickHandler>

        <div
          className="menu-icon"
          onClick={() => setMenuOpened((prev) => !prev)}
        >
          <BiMenuAltRight size={30} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom, and if you have defined your routes, you need to use / and not #.

Like this :

```
<div className="flexCenter h-menu" style={getMenuStyles(menuOpened)}>
        <a href="/">Courses</a>
        <a href="/getstarted">Get Started</a>
        <a href="/value">Our Values</a>
        <a href="/">Blog</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        <button className="button">
          <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Keep in mind that you need to match the routes to the names you specified when you defined them.